# Cant access Microsoft Graph through Visual Studio

Tags: c#, graph, microsoft-graph-api

When I try to access a user through Graph, I get this error: Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException Authorization_RequestDenied - Message: "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."

I have enabled permissions both in Tenant and within the user profile. What am I missing?

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

        var tenantId = tenantID;
        var clientId = clientID;
        var clientSecret = secret;

        var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
        {
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
        };

        var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
            tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);            

        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

        var me = await graphClient.Users["user@mail.com"].Request().GetAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(me.GivenName);
    }
```

Comment: Everything with your code looks okay and the problem is not in it.

Comment: Could you pls checking in Azure portal about the api permissions you added? You used client client flow as the auth provider and it requires application api permission. Your error messages indicating that you didn't give enough api permission. So 2 possible reasons. One is that you didn't give enough&correct api permission. Another one is that the api permission you added haven't taken effect. We may need to wait for a while. By the way, after adding api permissions, don't forget to click  the `admin consent button`.

Comment: Do you get any progress on your issue?

Comment: Yes, both of your comments were very helpful Ivan and Tiny. I'm now able to make the calls and have responses. Thank you very much, and sorry for the late answer, we had some issues that had to be resolved before continuing this.

Answer (score 0):

When we use `client credential flow` as the `authProvider`, we have to give `application` api permission

[image]

Pls make sure you added these 2 permissions.

[image]

`Insufficient privileges to complete the operation` --> I'm afraid you added the delegated api permissions.

[image]